# How to create a training set for sequence labelling

Tags: nlp, software-recommendation, labels

I have a bunch of unlabeled text data that I would like to hand label. Are there any tools out there that you can use to produce your own labels? Ideally it would show a sentence at a time and give me the option of choosing a label for each word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several tools for this you could check the [Stanford Simple Annotation Tool](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-manual-annotation-tool-2004-05-16.tar.gz), also [Brat](http://brat.nlplab.org/) has online demos. For a comprehensive list you could check this [question](https://www.quora.com/Natural-Language-Processing-What-are-the-best-tools-for-manually-annotating-a-text-corpus-with-entities-and-relationships) on Quora

Answer (score 0):

There are tools that can help you label text data. One option is to use a tool specifically designed for text labelling, such as **[Labelbox](https://labelbox.com/)** or **[Prodigy](https://prodi.gy/)**. These tools typically allow you to import your text data, view it one sentence or document at a time, and apply labels to each word or phrase.

- [**Prodigy**](https://prodi.gy/) is a scriptable annotation tool so efficient that data scientists can do the annotation themselves, enabling a new level of rapid iteration.
- **[LabelBox](https://labelbox.com/)** allows users to manage their data using their high powered AI-enabled tools for data labelling by automating the labelling process and training models for active learning and has API support.